Excel Data Validation not working at all times
I have this formula applied at N3
=AND(OR(N3="", M3<>""), OR(N3="", AND(AND(ISNUMBER(N3), N3>=0, N3=ROUND(N3, 2)), OR(N3="", J3="", J3<N3)))).

M3 formula is
=AND(OR(N3="", M3<>""), OR(M3="", AND(AND(ISNUMBER(M3), M3>=0, M3=ROUND(M3, 2)), OR(M3="", J3="", J3<M3)))).

My requirement is:

If N3 is provided, then M3 should also be provided
If N3 is provided, then N3 should be 2 decimal places number and N3 should be greater than J3.

The formula is working sometimes while not working at other times:
One of such cases:

Entered J3 as 9 - works
Entered N3 as 4 - data validation becomes true and pop up occurs - Expected
Entered M3 as 4 - data validation becomes true and pop up occurs - Expected
Entered M3 as 11 - works
Entered N3 as 4 - data validation becomes true and pop up occurs - Expected
Removed M3 - works
Entered N3 as 4 - works while this should have failed.

There are multiple cases where I am coming to this scenario.
I have spent a lot of time trying to debug this. Any help is appreciated.

Does M3 have data validation as well? What are initial values of cells before the case you provided?

Yes, M3 has datavalidation too. Initially everything is blank. Edited the question with validation for M3

It looks like Excel's feature.
After some research, I found what Excel rises the data validation error ONLY when the validation value drops to FALSE as result of the user input into the current cell.
If the validation value is already FALSE (as result of the complex validation formula which refers other cells) the new user input doesn't fire the validation error.
You need to redesign your validation formulas to avoid such situations. May be, you need to apply external calculation (in a separate cell) to check all required conditions.

How is it going?
